# Many Spring-Boot Microservices to be run in one IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, microservices, multi-module

I have 5 repositories, each one containing a spring-boot microservice. I don't want to open 5x IntelliJ, so I am happy using File->New->Module. The Services window offers me the option to bulk start/stop the services. I am happy with this almost. But every new fictive developer would need to import every module, and I want to tweak this little detail.

I tought of multi-module maven. So right now I have 1 repository with 5 subfolders, each one representing a spring-boot microservice. On the command-line it's easy to build everything with one maven call. But the IDE support is not that good. There are no run-configuration suggested, so I need to fill in everything myself (5 times). Thinking of fictive other developers this solution is not that ideal.

I am still in search of a practical solution. What do you suggest?

Comment: IntelliJ allows sharing run configurations. Click the "share through VCS" checkbox at the top.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. For the sake of completeness:

in .gitignore exchange .idea with .idea/* and !.idea/runConfigurations